# Birt Chart: How do I access an aggregation values from a bound dataSet via script

Tags: api, charts, render, birt, aggregation

Could someone help me with the following:

I have a chart element in .rptdesign file.  it uses the dataset that has three column bindings.  Two columns (**x**,**y**) came from the dataset and are used to make the plot.  I also have another column binding which is an aggregation (COUNT) on **x**.  Essentially I am trying to count how many points are in the dataSet. So far so good....

Now depending on how many points are the dataset, I would need to **dynamically** adjust the properties of the chart, through the `beforeGeneration()` event handler.

Question:  how do I access aggregation values from within the `beforeGeneration()` event handler as shown below:

```
function beforeGeneration( chart, icsc )
{
importPackage( Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.data.impl );
count = ?????  //GET_VALUE_FROM_AGGREGATOIN
}
```

Thanks!!